# What is the right way to mutate objects to avoid side effects?

Tags: php, unit-testing, architecture, immutability

I have a next system of objects (simple example):

```
class Grid
{
    public State $state;
    // Other fields

    public function __construct(State $state)
    {
        $this->state = $state;
    }

    // ...
}

class State
{
    public bool $isCompleted = false;
    public ?User $judge;
}

class User
{

}
```

Disclaimer: `Grid` class is a legacy ActiveRecord model which can't be covered by isolated unit tests because it writes to a database and changes some other data in the system. So I'm only interested in `State` class.

I need a mutator class for `State`. It must be easy to test. It's look like this:

```
class StateMutator
{
    public function mutate(State $state, array $changes):?State
    {
        // ...
        $state->isCompleted = true;
        // ...
        if(!$someCondition){
            return null;
        }
        // ...
        return $state;
    }
}
```

And it's used in this way:

```
/** @var Grid $grid */
/** @var array $changes */
$newState = (new StateMutator())->mutate($grid->state, $changes);
if($newState !== null){
    $grid->state = $newState;
}
// Some other changes in $grid
$grid->saveChanges();
```

It looks good. But something confuses me. If the mutator does some changes in an obtained object and returns `null` after this, so calling code will thinks that State hasn't changed - makes some other changes in it and save it to the database. But because PHP pass objects by reference, changes which the mutator made in the state object will be save to the database too. And it's a problem.

What should I do to avoid this problem?

I have two ways to solve this problem, but both of them have big problems.

1. If the mutator can't change the state object in any place inside it, it should revert changes which it has already done. But it's difficult to do or even impossible in some cases.
2. The mutator should clone the state, mutate it's copy and return it. But in this case the method will need much more memory (the state can have more then 1000 objects in it's property).

May be someone have any idea?

Comment: I think this "mutator" should not modify `$state`, if its job is only to return an updated state. Do you have reasons you want `$state` modified in `mutate()`?

Comment: Yes I agree with you. So i ask how can I do this? To return a new state the mutator should clone a source state. But is needs a lot of memory. And I search an other way to do it.

Comment: I do not understand why do you need `mutate()` to return anything. Can it not be just `void`? You're not using its return value anyway, except to assign it to `$grid->state` again, which is useless, if the object has already been mutated, right?

Comment: Cloning seems like the proper way to go about this. I also think `State` should be immutable, so as to guarantee one given state can never be altered. Is the memory thing such a big deal? You're saying "because PHP pass objects by reference" but if it didn't, cloning them is exactly what it'd do anyway.

Comment: Here's another idea - can you make a StateChangeHistory object which tracks what has happened to State, so that you can revert any changes made?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would generally avoid that objects can get into an invalid state. Your `State` object should have methods that either mutate its state or return a clone with the new state. These methods validate the input and mutate/return a clone only if the resulting state is valid. No need to keep track of changes and rolling back.